# Jboss server log is showig error

Tags: jboss

I am calling a script within main script to start the jboss sever after releasing the build on server.it is successfully starting the JBOSS but showing the below output in server/log/ server.log file and at the console output which is hanged.
To run the next build i need to kill this manually which is not appropriate.

```
 05:04:17,373 INFO  [AjpProtocol] Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-0.0.0.0-8209
05:04:17,451 INFO  [ServerImpl] JBoss (Microcontainer) [5.1.0.GA (build:    SVNTag=JBoss_5_1_0_GA date=200905221053)] Started in 2m:38s:444ms
05:04:20,912 WARN  [PropertyMessageResources]   Resource MessageResources_en_US.properties Not Found.
05:04:20,913 WARN  [PropertyMessageResources]   Resource MessageResources_en.properties Not Found.
```

Help would be really highly appreciable.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the part of the script that attempts to start the jboss server from the main script ?

Comment: Thanks Saif for you reply.calling script code is :sh jboss_start.sh start path of the directory jboss_home. however it is running properly but problem it is getting habged after showing "started in msg hh:mm:ss".

Comment: Check the answer I have posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, when you start your jboss server, it is not started as a background process and the console just sits there with the logs when server is started, that must be the reason why your script seems to hang , in reality it is just awaiting console output from the server.

To start jboss as background operation, replace the lines of code where you fire the run.sh in startup script with

`nohup /path/to/jboss_home/jboss/bin/run.sh -b0.0.0.0 > /tmp/logs/jbosslogs.log &`

This should start jboss in the background and redirect all startup logs to jbosslogs.log file. Since it is a background process, it will not hang at all.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.but i have also set the same parameter that you have mentioned.nohup ./run.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -c ${DEP_DIR} & >/dev/null 2>&1. 

To stop it from hanged at user promt i have redirected the jboss_start script output in to a log (jbfile as suggested by you..
now my user promt is showing no jboss log messages and its moving forward to run another part of main script.
But again my question remain same,if jboss script log is showing the output as mentioned in my first post. is it running fine or m mising something which will imapct my release
Thank you for the prompt help

Comment: The logs being showed on the console does not matter, if you remove the `> /tmp/logs/jbosslogs.log` part from my command that I shared, the output will be shown on the console. The last `&` is important though. The concern is with the run.sh of jboss, as I mentioned previously, by default it is a fore-ground script that waits for user prompt. _is it running fine or I am missing something which will impact my release_ It solely depends on your environment that you have setup. If you have a doubt, just run the script like before and verify whether everything is working fine on your end or not.